# Register PODS Custom Field with WPGraphQL

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-field, pods-framework

I've created a Custom Post Type called 'Item' and added a multi-upload file/image/video field type but I'm not able to figure out how to register that custom field with WPGraphQL. Here's how I registered my CPT with WPGraphQL:

```php
  add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', function( $args, $post_type ) {

    if ( 'item' === $post_type ) {
      $args['show_in_graphql'] = true;
      $args['graphql_single_name'] = 'item';
      $args['graphql_plural_name'] = 'items';
    }

    return $args;

  }, 10, 2 );
```

Any suggestions or can someone point me in the right direction for documentation? I've gotten different answers in my search and nothing has worked so far. Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a question for the developers of WPGraphQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This WPGraphQL recipe](https://www.wpgraphql.com/recipes/register-graphql-field-with-argument/) covers how to set up a new field using `register_graphql_field()` ([function doc](https://www.wpgraphql.com/functions/register_graphql_field/)) but it doesn't have any examples on how to pass in image/file fields. If I were doing this for a quick project, I would just output the information I needed without getting too complicated/deep into the API. But as it turns out..

Some good news if you're looking to make things easier for yourself -- work on Pods 2.8 (in beta right now) has enabled more WPGraphQL capability for Pods. I was able to build out an entire [Pods Pro WPGraphQL Add-On](https://pods-pro.skc.dev/downloads/wpgraphql-integration/) which allows you to set up GraphQL access for whole Pods as well as all/individual fields in that Pod. I put extra attention into making sure that relationships and file fields are well represented in the GraphQL structure, you should check out the [demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmrAKrRa9QY).

Comment: Thanks, for the tip @ScottKingsleyClark! And thanks for the work you're doing on Pods. It's really a great tool. You're the man.

Answer (score 0):

So after some more digging and looking through more of the docs I came up with this solution that seems to be working. I'm not sure if this is the "blessed" way but I think it gets the job done in a pinch.

Registering my Pods CPT:

```php
  add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', function( $args, $post_type ) {

    if ( 'item' === $post_type ) {
      $args['show_in_graphql'] = true;
      $args['graphql_single_name'] = 'item';
      $args['graphql_plural_name'] = 'items';
    }

    return $args;

  }, 10, 2 );
```

adding an action that registers a new object type (`GalleryImage`) and only returns the `guid` by calling `register_graphql_object_type`. Then I call `register_graphql_field` and expects to return a `list_of` `galleryImage` objects. The part I'm not totally sure of is the resolver function getting the `item` pod and returning the `gallery` field. It works and makes sense but I'm sure it can be optimized.

```php
  add_action( 'graphql_register_types', function() {

    register_graphql_object_type(
      'GalleryImage',
      [
        'description' => __( 'Gallery Image' ),
        'fields'      => [
          'guid'  => [
            'type'        => 'String',
            'description' => 'image guid'
          ]
        ],
      ]
    );

    register_graphql_field(
      'Item',
      'galleryImages',
      [
        'description' => __( 'Return images' ),
        'type' => [ 'list_of' => 'galleryImage' ],
        'resolve' => function() {
          $images = pods( 'item', [ 'limit' => -1 ])->field( 'gallery' );
          return $images;
        }
      ]
    );
  } );
```

[These docs](https://www.wpgraphql.com/recipes/register-object-and-field-for-custom-list-of-users/) were really helpful.